# How to read from bluetooth device to an android app.

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am trying to read test from a HC-06 Bluetooth module that is connected to a arduino.  I know they are connected.  I send text to arduino and in return it does something but then I would like to read the Serial.print("something") from the arduino.  I get a value larger than 0 from bytesAvailable but I can't seem to figure out how to actually read it so I can print it somewhere.  Any ideas?

It prints all the Logs to Log.e("Connection", "BEFORE WHILE");, but then it seems to get stuck when it tries to read the bufferreader but it won't give me an error to troubleshoot with.

```
    private void fromArduino()
            {
                if (btSocket!=null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        inStream = btSocket.getInputStream();

                        int bytesAvailable = inStream.available();
                    Log.e("Connection",String.valueOf(bytesAvailable));

                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        while(true) {
                            Log.e("Connection", "IN IF STATE");
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            readBufferPosition = inStream.read(packetBytes);
                            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream, "US-ASCII"));
                            Result = "";
                            String line = "";
                            Log.e("Connection", "BEFORE WHILE");
                            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                            Log.e("Connection", line);
                        /*while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                            Log.e("Connection",line);
                            Result+=line;
                        }*/
                            bufferedReader.close();
                            inStream.close();
                            Log.e("Connection", "FINISH");
                        }
                        /*for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];

                            byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                            System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                            final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                            readBufferPosition = 0;
                        }*/
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```